# Cross site authentication with Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am wondering whether it is possible to create cross site authentication between an asp.net mvc application and an umbraco site. They are on different domains. I know there are at least a few methods to do this, such as SSO and using machine key for cookies.

I'm not sure whether this will be possible with Umbraco though. On the other hand I thought that because of Umbraco's support for the latest Razor and using MVC this may be able to work.

Can anyone help? Thanks